# URL Redirection

Tags: url, url-rewriting

How do I set it up so that when someone goes to `www.example.com/file1.mp3`, they get redirected to `www.example.com/file2.mp3`, but the address in the browser bar stays the same?

Comment: what technology(ASP.NET/PHP) are you using? For ASP.NET you can use Server.Transfer("www.mysite.pl/file2.mp3")

Comment: We'll need to know what web server you're using (and also, I think this is one for ServerFault).

Answer (score 0):

the company you get your domain applies setting for that, there should be a option to change it. i really don't know whether you can handle it by a piece of code but the setting for the domain name is applied  in that way.contact where you get your domain name or see the settings.

Answer (score 0):

If using an Apache server, you can do it via `.htaccess`:

```
Alias /file1.mp3 /file2.mp3
```

([Docs for the `alias` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias))

Also, you can dig into the whole [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) thing.